# "readBundle: bad magic number" error while getting String from bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I am passing the bundle inside intent from one class to another. But while receiving it i am getting the error something like "readBundle: bad magic number". Here is a code snippet

Passing bundle from class A:

```
  Intent intent  = new Intent();
  Bundle b1=new Bundle();
  b1.putString("STORE_STATUS", "true");
  b1.putParcelableArrayList("ParticularStoreInfo", particularStoreInfoArr);
  intent.putExtra("BundleData", b1);
  intent.setAction(Tag);
  context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Receveing it in class B :

```
bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("BundleData");
if(bundle!=null){
String SEARCH_STATUS = bundle.getString("STORE_STATUS");// error on this line
if(SEARCH_STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){  


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (bundle  != null) {
 String SEARCH_STATUS = bundle.getString("STORE_STATUS");
   if (datas!= null) {
        // do stuff
   }
```

**Edited:**

And to send the data to the activity use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("STORE_STATUS", "SOME DATAS");
```

**Answer of your query:**

To use Bundle to send data with your Intent you have to use this like:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.extras.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

Comment: i have done something like this.. similar to your suggestion Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (bundle  != null) {
 String SEARCH_STATUS = bundle.getString("STORE_STATUS");
   if (SEARCH_STATUS != null) {
        // do stuff
   }   and now getting null pointer exception on SEARCH_STATUS

Comment: Its working now but why it is happening that whenever i am sending any parceble object inside bundle, it receives null on receiver.

Answer (score 0):

> Intents are sent from one component to another(not between two classes
>   in general).   Assuming B is broadcast receiver(you have used
>   sendBroadcast) and A as sender, B has to receive the intent after
>   sendBroadcast().
>
> You have used putExtra, putString and putParceableArrayList. So on the
>   receiving side, try using getExtra, getString and
>   getParceableArrayList.
>
> If you are trying to use the intent's bundle on the receiver method
>   which has no intent as parameter, you can use getIntent()..
>
> If you are confused by this answer, please post your complete or
>   sample code you want to resolve, else ignore.